# Google Geochart: Highlighting by continent & country (multiple resolutions)

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to make a google chart that highlights different regions continents, or countries based on a particular grouping.

The problem is I can't figure the best way to show both `continents` and `countries`.

For instance, I'd like to have two highlighted entries: Europe and Japan.

I can use the below JS code to attempt this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Region', 'Label', {role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}],
    ['150', 1, 'Europe'],
    ['Japan', 2, 'Japan']
]);

var options = {
    resolution: 'continents',
}
  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, options);
};
```

The above code partly works- Europe is properly highlighted and labelled. However, because `resolution` is set to `'continents'` Japan does not get highlighted. If I set `resolution` to `'countries'` the opposite problem occurs.

So the real question:

Is there a way to highlight both Europe and Japan individually with one array entry each, or do I have to put every single European country in the list to also have Japan highlighted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you would need to *put every single European country in the list to also have Japan highlighted*

another option might be to draw two charts, one on top of the other,
using the following config options to allow the bottom one to show thru.

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
```

however, this would suppress the tooltip on the bottom chart.

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['geochart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Region', 'Label', {role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}],
    ['150', 1, 'Europe']
  ]);

  var options1 = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
    resolution: 'continents'
  }

  var geochart1 = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
    document.getElementById('visualization1')
  );
  geochart1.draw(data1, options1);

  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Region', 'Label', {role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}],
    ['Japan', 2, 'Japan']
  ]);

  var options2 = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
    resolution: 'countries'
  }

  var geochart2 = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
    document.getElementById('visualization2')
  );
  geochart2.draw(data2, options2);
}
```

```css
.geo {
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="geo" id="visualization1"></div>
<div class="geo" id="visualization2"></div>
```

**note:** `jsapi` should no longer be used to load the charts library,
according to the release notes...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. The last update, for security purposes, was with a pre-release of v45. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I think for purely visual purposes your strategy would work. However, one part I didn't include in the question is that there is a interactive component to this- Clicking a region/country opens a link with data about that region. I think I'll have to go with the 'add every country' to the list which is tedious, but not difficult.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it technically answers the original question posed as well as the high quality of the answer, although it was not the solution for me.